# JAVA: parseInt problems

Tags: java, parseint

I get the following error

```
Driver.java:237: cannot find symbol  
symbol  : method parseInt(char)
location: class java.lang.Integer
int bp = Integer.parseInt(b);
```

when using this code

```
char  p = switchchar.charAt(6);
    char  b = switchchar.charAt(7);
    int pp = Integer.parseInt(p);
    int bp = Integer.parseInt(b);
```

In the documentation it says the method should be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the [`Integer#parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method takes in a `String` and not a `char`. To get the numeric value from a char, use the [`Character#getNumericValue(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29).

```
int pp = Character.getNumericValue(p);
int bp = Character.getNumericValue(b);
```

Comment: Oh, how didn't I notice that... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to turn the char into a String before parseInt will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The parseInt method receives a String as its parameter, not a char, so you have to do something like this:

```
String  p = "" + switchchar.charAt(6);
String  b = "" + switchchar.charAt(7);
int pp = Integer.parseInt(p);
int bp = Integer.parseInt(b);
```